# Im trying to make a simple password confirmation

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

I'm trying to compare two strings or see if they would be equal.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Insert PassWord.");

            string passWord1 = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Confirm PassWord.");

            string passWord2 = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

            if (passWord1.Equals(passWord2))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PassWords Match");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: PassWords do not Match");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Continue");

        }
```

so basically if the two strings are equal then it would say they match, but the problem is, is that after you input both the strings the console exits out. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`Console.ReadKey()`** after **`Console.WriteLine();`**, so that it will wait until you respond with a key,

```
 Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Continue");
 Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! it worked. I forgot to put that there.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Insert PassWord.");

        string passWord1 = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Confirm PassWord.");

        string passWord2 = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

        if (passWord1.Equals(passWord2))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PassWords Match");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: PassWords do not Match");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

When you do not use Console.Readkey() or any another input function the program will terminate after showing `Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Continue");`. It will show Press Enter To Continue but so fast that you cannot observe.